# What does R.drawable.image return?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView ballDisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_eightBall);

        final int[] ballArray = {R.drawable.ball1,
                R.drawable.ball2,
                R.drawable.ball3,
                R.drawable.ball4,
                R.drawable.ball5};//*******What integer is that???????????

        Button myButon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.askButton);
        myButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
                int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(5);
                ballDisplay.setImageResource(ballArray[number]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**What is the value stored in that intger?**

Comment: read about `@+id`

Comment: Why are you so concerned in knowing the id values?

Comment: I later realized that the question was't relevant. I'm not going to need that information ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't really need to know the actual value of `R.drawable.ball5` as it is determined during the build.... but I won't second guess your question-- the actual value of `R.drawable.ball5` can be found in the file `R.java` in the build folder that's created during the build.

To find it in Android Studio, after you've done a build you can right-click on `R.drawable.ball5` in the editor, then **Go To -> Implementation(s)** and you'll see the generated `R.Java` file as well as the number that is assigned to this resource for this build.  It looks like:

```
public static final int ball5=0x7f080093;
```

Programmatically, you can just log `Integer.toString(R.drawable.ball5)`.

That's the answer to the question you asked.  But I think you'd be better off looking at `R.id.ball5` for example to explicitly name the resource or reference the drawable by the name "ball5" and refer to it with that variable name.  You shouldn't really care about what value `R.drawable.ball5` actually is as it will likely change as you add or remove other resources.

Something like this might work better insofar as I can guess what you're trying to do:

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
            Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
            int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(5);
            ballDisplay.setImageDrawable(this,
                   getDrawable(ballArray[number]));
            }
```

If you want to get the drawable using a method that supports older APIs, try:

```
           ballDisplay.setImageDrawable(
                   this.getResources()
                  .getDrawable(ballArray[number]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Drawables data type isn't an int; your reference to it is an int, which you can see in R.java.

```
final int[] ballArray = 
           {R.drawable.ball1,
            R.drawable.ball2,
            R.drawable.ball3,
            R.drawable.ball4,
            R.drawable.ball5};
```

so here your are only storing reference.

Answer (score 1):

R.drawable.image stores a resource id which will return an int.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to know what value it returns because you already know how to access it, and, you cannot know it initially because the value is determined during the build time, all you can know at the start is that it is a number in hexa decimal
Still if you want to know after the build completes go to R.java file there you will find it.

Answer (score -1):

R.drawable.image means the drawable resource, in this case image. Drawable means graphic which can be drawn. Every drawable is stored in res/drawable folder. Your ballArray is the array of drawables.